# Replace a simple image within a DMG file

Tags: images, dmg-image

i have a DMG file that has a gatekeeper , i would like to edit the image of the gatekeeper
And repplace it with 1 of my own with my own design.

i have attemped the long route which was to extract the DMG using 7zip, replace the image then attempt to create a DMG again with the extracted data.

However i ran into and error (Disk utility) Status 17 : File exists

i was left with an unopenable DMG file (the new 1)

im hoping that there might be a much simpler way to do this, if not then why did i get the status 17.

thank you for any help.

Comment: Why are you using 7zip on a .dmg? What makes you think the .dmg is writable? [Most aren't] Are you trying to do this on Windows rather than Mac? On Mac you would convert the .dmg to writable, swap in your file, then convert it back. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228116/add-delete-modify-files-within-a-disk-image-dmg